# Updating Document in MongoDB without Alphabetically order

Tags: c, mongodb

I am making one project on MongoDB and inserted some documents and now i am updating the documents by this code..

```
bson_init( query );

bson_append_string(query, "First", "A");
bson_append_string(query, "Second", "B");
bson_append_string(query, "Third", "C");
bson_append_string(query, "Fourth", "D");
bson_append_string(query, "Fifth", "E");

bson_finish(query );


bson_init( b );
bson_append_start_object(b,"$set");

if(checkBox_First->isChecked() == true)
bson_append_string( b, "First", "Z");

if(checkBox_Second->isChecked() == true)
bson_append_string( b, "Second", "X");

if(checkBox_Third->isChecked() == true)
bson_append_string( b, "Third", "R");

if(checkBox_Fourth->isChecked() == true)
bson_append_string( b, "Fourth", "Y");

if(checkBox_Fifth->isChecked() == true)
bson_append_string( b, "Fifth","P");

bson_append_finish_object( b );

bson_finish(b );

mongo_update(conn,TEST_NS,query,b,MONGO_UPDATE_BASIC,0);
bson_destroy(query);
bson_destroy(b);
```

The code is working perfectly but after updating, the document is stored in Alphabetical order. Can anyone tell me how i can update document without sorting alphabetically. I am using `"$set"` Update parameter. I am using C Driver.

Comment: What does this question have to do with the qt tag? Removing it... Feel free to add it back once it is clear why it is related to Qt.

Comment: `if(checkBox_Fifth->isChecked() == true)`..this condition is from Qt...I am taking inputs from a GUI..

Comment: What does the checkbox have to do with your alphabetical db ordering issue?

Comment: The checkbox is there to tell which fields to update in the DB.

Comment: It could be anything, even a console application triggering the same issue.

Comment: It can be but not my case..mine is taking inputs from GUI...

Comment: Please accept that your issue is not emanating from Qt. It is a generic monodb sorting issue as it currently looks. Feel free to add the tag back once it is more sure that it is coming from Qt.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to ensure that the order of top level fields is as you wish is to set the entire document at once.  If you have certain fields in the document already, `$set` operator does not have a way to specify where in the document you want the new fields added.

Starting with the next version (2.6, currently available as unstable development release 2.5.x) this behavior will change and the fields in the document will not be reordered.  Depending on when you will be deploying your application you may try the development release and once 2.6 is out deploy with that version.

Please note that normally the top level field order does not matter, and generally is not guaranteed.

Comment: You mentioned version 2.6...i think you are talking about C++ driver but my case is about C driver which have the latest version of 0.85....so i am just wondering whether it is similar for both drivers or there is some thing different in C Driver...thanks